# Issue getting query from $_REQUEST because of redirect

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

The code below deals with connecting to the LInkedIn API via PHP CodeIgniter and worked well for a long time until I added internationalization changing the URLs and adding redirects.

I fixed the URLs so they're unchanged with the exception of /en/ language segment.

After authorizing on LinkedIn I still get undefined index errors, but I see the variables in the link of my browser.

What I don't understand why then $_REQUEST doesn't 'see'either oauth_token or oauth_verifier when they're in the URL?

First Error: Undefined index: oauth_verifier

Link:

http://www.youinapage.com/en/linklogin/get_resume_linkedin?oauth_token=e68974fc-5ba9-41d8-bc2f-9b33a5e59961&oauth_verifier=07539

Code Sample:

```
    session_start();
    $this->load->library('format');

    $config['linkedin_access'] = "---";
    $config['linkedin_secret'] = "---";
    $config['base_url']  = site_url('linklogin/initiate/');
    $config['callback_url']  = site_url('linklogin/get_resume_linkedin/');

        # First step is to initialize with your consumer key and secret. We'll use an out-of-band oauth_callback
$linkedin = new LinkedIn($config['linkedin_access'], $config['linkedin_secret'], $config['callback_url'] );
//$linkedin->debug = true;

   if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){
        $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']     = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
        $linkedin->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = serialize($linkedin->access_token);
        header("Location: " . $config['callback_url']);
        exit;
   }
   else{


        $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']); 
        $linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];  //GENERATE INITIAL ERROR
        $linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);
   }
```

Comment: Yup. I expanded my code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not from $_REQUEST but from $_SESSION.

If you look carefully the errors output it says the first error is on

```
$_SESSION['requestToken']
```

And then indeed, the engine fails as well on

```
$_SESSION['oauth_verifier']
```

for an unknown reason though but that implies a certainly different issue, (I think)

Rgds.

Comment: Thought about that - but if that was the case -- then wouldn't it go within `if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'])){` instead of `else`?

Comment: I see, I don't have the line numbers to actually check this. You confirm that the line 159 is within the else block?

Comment: Yup I put a comment next to the specific line because that was my thought before I posted.